# jackd does not recognize sound card (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, jack

I cloned the hard drive from an existing machine onto an SSD to be put into a new machine (Dell Optiplex 7050 Tower). Whenever I try to start the JACK server, I get this error:

```
10:37:17.310 Patchbay deactivated.
10:37:17.312 Statistics reset.
10:37:17.314 ALSA connection change.
10:37:17.337 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
10:37:42.348 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Tue Mar 27 10:37:17 2018: Starting jack server...
Tue Mar 27 10:37:17 2018: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Tue Mar 27 10:37:17 2018: Acquired audio card Audio0
Tue Mar 27 10:37:17 2018: creating alsa driver ... hw:Intel,3|hw:Intel,3|1024|3|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|16bit
Tue Mar 27 10:37:17 2018: ERROR: ALSA: Cannot open PCM device alsa_pcm for capture. Falling back to playback-only mode
Tue Mar 27 10:37:17 2018: configuring for 48000Hz, period = 1024 frames (21.3 ms), buffer = 3 periods
Tue Mar 27 10:37:17 2018: ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
Tue Mar 27 10:37:17 2018: ALSA: use 3 periods for playback
Tue Mar 27 10:37:22 2018: ERROR: JackPosixProcessSync::LockedTimedWait error usec = 5000000 err = Connection timed out
Tue Mar 27 10:37:22 2018: ERROR: Driver is not running
Tue Mar 27 10:37:22 2018: ERROR: Cannot open client name = dbusapi
Tue Mar 27 10:37:22 2018: ERROR: failed to create dbusapi jack client
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
10:37:42.352 ALSA connection graph change.
10:37:49.556 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Server communication error. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot read socket fd = 25 err = Success
CheckRes error
JackSocketClientChannel read fail
Cannot open qjackctl client
Tue Mar 27 10:37:49 2018: ERROR: ALSA: poll time out, polled for 31999229 usecs
Tue Mar 27 10:37:49 2018: ERROR: JackAudioDriver::ProcessAsync: read error, stopping...
Tue Mar 27 10:37:49 2018: ERROR: JackPosixProcessSync::LockedTimedWait error usec = 5000000 err = Connection timed out
Tue Mar 27 10:37:49 2018: ERROR: Driver is not running
Tue Mar 27 10:37:49 2018: ERROR: Cannot create new client
Tue Mar 27 10:37:49 2018: Released audio card Audio0
Tue Mar 27 10:37:49 2018: Saving settings to "/home/programming/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
```

The problem seems to stem from the Alsa driver behaving incorrectly with the sound card in the new machine.

Initially, I suspected that the soundcard may not be selected as the input/output device in the settings accessible through the JACK gui.

To verify it was trying to grab the new sound card, as opposed to the non-existent cards in the old machine, I checked the output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: ID 280b Digital [ID 280b Digital]
    Subdevices: 1/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The specific model (from what I can tell from the Dell specs sheet) is ALC 3234.

I found that it was set to "hw:PCH" as the input/output device, and I changed it to "hw:Intel,3" from the drop down menu for both I/O. I rebooted, but received the same error when trying to launch the JACK server.

Looking into this further, I found that for some people with a similar problem, PulseAudio was grabbing the sound card before JACK could. I tried setting `autospawn = no` in `~/.pulse/client.conf` and rebooting, but no success there either.

Even tried installing the most recent backports of alsa-base (for 14.04), with no luck there either.

Here's the relevant bit of `lshw` if it helps:

```
*-multimedia
         description: Audio device
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 00
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
         resources: irq:149 memory:f7240000-f7243fff memory:f7220000-f722ffff
```

Any help in solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oBZZ3MgXZPjLvCzIrLv3IkvUFqMiiTZO/view?usp=sharing) is the output of alsa-info.sh, which I found from an [troubleshooting guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)